# Applying styles and including shortcodes in page.php - wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to include few shorcodes and few bullet items in my page.php file to make sure that the plug in appears in all pages. i am doing this as i dont have any widget areas. but the plugin does not appear in the pages and the style for the bullet items also are not applied.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: how did you add yur shortcode in page.php

Comment: i am doing this <?php if ( function_exists( 'get_testimonial_slider' ) ) {
  get_testimonial_slider(); } ?>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want to include shortcodes in php templates in Wordpress, you can use this code:

```
<?php do_shortcode('[shortcode]'); ?>
```

Comment: i am doing this <?php if ( function_exists( 'get_testimonial_slider' ) ) {
  get_testimonial_slider(); } ?>